# Python converts string into tuple

Tags: python

Example:

```
regular_string = "%s %s" % ("foo", "bar")

result = {}
result["somekey"] = regular_string,

print result["somekey"]
# ('foo bar',)
```

Why `result["somekey"]` tuple now not string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because of comma at the end of the line.

Answer (score 9):

When you write

```
result["somekey"] = regular_string,
```

Python reads

```
result["somekey"] = (regular_string,)
```

`(x,)` is the syntax for a tuple with a single element. Parentheses are assumed. And you really end up putting a tuple, instead of a string there.